# Where can you find your actions in google-home app which is not deployed but still in development phase

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I am developing actions for google home. It is still in development phase. I have developed music actions and the songs are playing fine in google-home. I am performing account linking which is also working properly by getting account linking card in home page of google home app. All I want to know is where can i find my actions in google-home app where i can see link/unlink buttons to my actions.

Like in Alexa app i was able to see my skills in your skills -> dev skills section. Is there any way in google-home app like this where i can link/unlink actions. I have checked but i am not able to find this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look the [Actions Directory](https://developers.google.com/actions/distribute/directory). On your phone, you can search and find the action, and then see specific controls for the action like unlinking and clearing user storage.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Its working properly. We have to complete the directory information in google actions console.